# Accessing imgUr thru OAuth (uploading to user account)

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, file-upload, imgur

To start doing this "simple" task I've researched for a procedure that I've taken as an example [here](http://pc-tips.net/imgur-api-vb-net/) to follow and reproduce the steps, the procedure can upload an image "anonymously":

```
Private ReadOnly ClientId As String = "My Client ID" ' => "..............."
Private ReadOnly ClientSecret As String = "My Client Secret" ' => "........................................"

' Usage:
' Dim url As String = UploadImage("C:\Image.jpg") : MessageBox.Show(url)
Public Function UploadImage(ByVal image As String)

    Dim w As New WebClient()
    w.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " & ClientId)
    Dim Keys As New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection

    Try

        Keys.Add("image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(image)))
        Dim responseArray As Byte() = w.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", Keys)
        Dim result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
        Dim reg As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("link"":""(.*?)""")
        Dim match As Match = reg.Match(result)
        Dim url As String = match.ToString.Replace("link"":""", "").Replace("""", "").Replace("\/", "/")
        Return url

    Catch s As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. " & s.Message)
        Return "Failed!"

    End Try

End Function
```

But what I really would like to do is upload the image into my user account, which is [http://elektrostudios.imgur.com](https://elektrostudios.imgur.com/all).

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448005/how-do-i-upload-to-an-imgur-users-account) question but what him said in the answer is not clear for my (due to my newbie knowledges), anyways I've tried to use the function above but just sending the `BEARER` header with my `ClientSecret` ID 'cause If I understood good what the [oauth 2 api documentation](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2#making_request) says the token could also be the `ClientSecret` Id?, but I don't get the expected result.

So searching the way to get a proper acces token I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528799/box-access-token-api-v2) else question which helped me to discover [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) library and to know how to send the request, I did some modifications to use it with Imgur API but I'm getting this error-response:

```
{"data":{"error":"client_id and response_type are required","request":"\/oauth2\/authorize","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":400}
```

This is what I have:

```
Public Sub GetAccessToken()

    Dim xrc As RestClient = New RestClient
    Dim grant_type As String = "authorization_code"
    Dim request As New RestRequest(Method.POST)
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim response As RestResponse
    Dim strResponse As String

    request.Method = Method.POST
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml

    'Base URL
    xrc.BaseUrl = "https://api.imgur.com"

    'Resource
    request.Resource = "oauth2/authorize"

    'Format body
    strBody = String.Format("client_id={0}&response_type={1}", ClientId, ClientSecret)

    'Add body to request
    request.AddBody("Authorization", strBody)

    'Execute
    response = xrc.Execute(request)

    'Parse Response
    strResponse = response.Content

    MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ToString)

End Sub
```

**So my question are 2 in 1:**

> How I can upload an Image into an Imgur user
>   account using the required things such as the access token?.

PS: Please remember that even getting the access token I don't know how to use it after stored it.

> UPDATE:

I'm trying to use @**Plutonix** solution but when I try to request the Token it throws an exception "`Need a valid PIN first`", I'm using a valid ClientId and ClientSecret, I'm missing something more?, here is the code:

```
Private imgUR As New imgurAPI("my client id", "my client secret")

Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click

    Dim wb As New WebBrowser
    imgUR.RequestPinBrowser(wb)

    ' The instruction below throws an exception:
    ' "Need a valid PIN first"
    Dim result As imgurAPI.imgUrResults = imgUR.RequestToken
    wb.Dispose()

    ' check result
    If result = imgurAPI.imgUrResults.OK Then

        ' assumes the file exists
        imgUR.UploadImage("C:\Test.jpg", False)

        Clipboard.SetText(imgUR.LastImageLink)
        MessageBox.Show(imgUR.LastImageLink)

    Else
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error getting access token. Status:{0}",
            result.ToString))
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to be on point. No one would like to read such long questions and codes. Including me! :P

Comment: If someone writes a tiny question ...bad, if someone write a big question ...bad too, downvotes for stupid things. I just tried to do a good question giving all what I've researched and all what I have, and that is what is expected from every S.O. user. But I'm with you in one thing: Only users with the gentleness to read a question should comment or answer (or vote). PS: Annyways those are not "long codes" in any way.

Comment: This is a fact! It's true! And writing long codes and questions is not expected from a S.O. user. Who told you that? See the how to ask page, it clearly mentions in bold not to post the whole code. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've posted an entire Class of 1.000 lines?, not, I've just shared two procedures (tiny procedures) which are the Core of the question, what you want... only two lines of code there? that should help you to understand more the question? I don't understand you. also you should read more: `Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs` so please, stop doing this thing here, does not helps.

Comment: Mate, look! You have more reputation than me. I didn't mean to trouble you. Sharing your research doesn't mean posting whole code, just the relevant one. I am sorry if it did hurt you.

Comment: The thing is that what you consider the "whole code" isn't, is only the relevant code to fix/improve. But ok no matter, please stop here, thanks for comment.

Comment: have you seen this? http://pc-tips.net/imgur-api-vb-net/

Comment: @Plutonix yes I saw it, please, read the first phrase of my post and you'll found an hyperlink that points to that reference that you've commented. But that example does not introduce about how to upload to an account. thanks for comment!

Comment: sorry, that one little word did not stand out as a link.  i have an api3 bit of code for you to try...  Not sure if I should post it since I dont have an imgur acct to test it.  it is supposed to work though

Comment: @Plutonix I understand you, don't worry, anyways imgur account registration is free and only takes one minute http://imgur.com/register and imgur API usage registration is also free here http://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient if you could register for test your code and share the (good) results to solve this question I will appreciate it, if not then thankyou anyways for your time!

Comment: I am not a joiner, especially if they ask for an email address.  Since I havent personally tested it, I was going to post/send it to the link in your profile for you to test, but I am not joining that either.

Comment: @Plutonix I didn't noted that your intentions was mean to send it me via email (remember you know that my English is not very good), sorry If I've offended you in some way telling you about register in imgur (seems that) but was not my intention, I've just seen in that moment the registration alternative instead the email on my perfil (just i'll clarify it), I respect your decission 'cause it's private material, really no problem you've always helped me a lot, thanks again this time to have tried it.

Comment: I wasnt offended, just stating that I dont join stuff lightly, esp with emails.  I can upload Anon, but you want to the Acct (you **do** know  that is a **manual** step unless you ask for the name and password and scrape, right?).  Anyway, I can get the PIN in code, but stuck at the moment submitting it to get the Access Token (which kinds sounds like where you are).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is long, because it is more or less a compleat API:

```vb
Public Class imgurAPI
    ' combination of this API and imgUR server responses
    Public Enum imgUrResults
        OK = 200                        ' AKA Status200 

        ' errors WE return
        OtherAPIError = -1              ' so far, just missing ImgLink
        InvalidToken = -2
        InvalidPIN = -3                 ' pins expire
        InvalidRequest = -4
        TokenParseError = -5

        ' results we get from server
        BadRequestFormat = 400          ' Status400   
        AuthorizationError = 401        ' Status401  

        Forbidden = 403                 ' Status403   
        NotFound = 404                  ' Status404   ' bad URL Endpoint
        RateLimitError = 429            ' Status429   ' RateLimit Error
        ServerError = 500               ' Status500   ' internal server error

        UknownStatus = 700              ' We havent accounted for it (yet), 
                                        '   may be trivial or new
    End Enum

    ' container for the cool stuff they send us
    Friend Class Token
        Public Property AcctUserName As String
        Public Property AccessToken As String
        Public Property RefreshToken As String
        Public Property Expiry As DateTime

        Public Sub New()
            AcctUserName = ""
            AccessToken = ""
            RefreshToken = ""
            Expiry = DateTime.MinValue
        End Sub

        Friend Function IsExpired() As Boolean

            If (Expiry > DateTime.Now) Then
                Return False
            Else
                ' if expired reset everything so some moron doesnt
                ' expose AccessToken and test for ""
                AcctUserName = ""
                AccessToken = ""
                RefreshToken = ""
                Expiry = DateTime.MinValue
                Return True
            End If
        End Function

    End Class

    ' NO simple ctor!!!
    ' constructor initialized with ClientID and SecretID
    Public Sub New(clID As String, secret As String)
        clientID = clID
        clientSecret = secret
        myPin = ""
        imgToken = New Token
        LastImageLink = ""
        UseClipboard = True
        AnonOnly = False
    End Sub

    ' constructor initialized with ClientID and SecretID
    Public Sub New(clID As String)
        clientID = clID
        clientSecret = ""
        myPin = ""
        imgToken = New Token
        LastImageLink = ""
        UseClipboard = True
        AnonOnly = True
    End Sub


    Private clientID As String
    Private clientSecret As String

    Private AnonOnly As Boolean = True

    ' tokens are not public
    Private imgToken As Token

    Public Property LastImageLink As String

    Public Property UseClipboard As Boolean

    ' precise moment when it expires for use in code
    Public ReadOnly Property TokenExpiry As DateTime
        Get
            If imgToken IsNot Nothing Then
                Return imgToken.Expiry
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function GetExpiryCountdown() As String
        Return String.Format("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", GetExpiryTimeRemaining)
    End Function

    ' time left as a TimeSpan
    Public Function GetExpiryTimeRemaining() As TimeSpan
        Dim ts As New TimeSpan(0)

        If imgToken Is Nothing Then
            Return ts
        End If

        If DateTime.Now > imgToken.Expiry Then
            Return ts
        Else
            ts = imgToken.Expiry - DateTime.Now
            Return ts
        End If

    End Function

    Public Function IsTokenValid() As Boolean

        If imgToken Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgToken.AcctUserName) Then
            Return False
        End If

        If imgToken.IsExpired Then
            Return False
        End If

        Return True

    End Function

    ' Currently, the PIN is set from a calling App.  Might be possible
    ' to feed the log in to imgUr to get a PIN
    Private myPin As String
    Public WriteOnly Property Pin As String
        Set(value As String)
            myPin = value
        End Set
    End Property


    ' Navigates to the web page.
    ' see wb_DocumentCompleted for code to 
    ' parse the PIN from the document
    Public Sub RequestPinBrowser(BrowserCtl As WebBrowser)

        If AnonOnly Then
            ' you do not need a PIN for Anon
            Throw New ApplicationException("A PIN is not needed for ANON Uploads")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If BrowserCtl Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Missing a valid WebBrowser reference")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' imgur API format
        ' https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=REQUESTED_RESPONSE_TYPE&state=APPLICATION_STATE

        Dim OAuthUrlTemplate = "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type={1}&state={2}"
        Dim ReqURL As String = String.Format(OAuthUrlTemplate, clientID, "pin", "ziggy")

        BrowserCtl.Url = New Uri(ReqURL)
    End Sub


    Public Function GetAccessToken() As imgUrResults
        ' there are different types of token requests
        ' which vary only by the data submitted

        Dim sReq As String = String.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=pin&pin={2}",
                                            clientID, clientSecret, myPin)
        If myPin = String.Empty Then
            Return imgUrResults.InvalidPIN
        End If

        If AnonOnly Then Return imgUrResults.InvalidRequest

        ' call generic token processor
        Return RequestToken(sReq)

    End Function

    ' request a Token 
    Private Function RequestToken(sRequest As String) As imgUrResults
        Dim url As String = "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token/"

        Dim myResult As imgUrResults = imgUrResults.OK

        ' create request for the URL, using POST method
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Method = "POST"

        ' convert the request, set content format, length
        Dim data As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sRequest)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = data.Length

        ' write the date to request stream
        Dim dstream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
        dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        dstream.Close()

        ' json used on the response and potential WebException
        Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer()

        ' prepare for a response
        Dim response As WebResponse = Nothing
        Dim SvrResponses As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        Try
            response = request.GetResponse
            ' convert status code to programmatic result
            myResult = GetResultFromStatus(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)

        Catch ex As WebException
            ' a bad/used pin will throw an exception
            Dim resp As String = New StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

            SvrResponses = CType(json.DeserializeObject(resp.ToString), 
                                    Dictionary(Of String, Object))
            myResult = GetResultFromStatus(Convert.ToString(SvrResponses("status")))

        End Try

        'Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        'Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)

        ' premature evacuation
        If myResult <> imgUrResults.OK Then
            If dstream IsNot Nothing Then
                dstream.Close()
                dstream.Dispose()
            End If
            If response IsNot Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If

            Return myResult
        End If

        ' read the response stream
        dstream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim SvrResponseStr As String
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dstream)
            ' stream to string
            SvrResponseStr = sr.ReadToEnd
            'Console.WriteLine(SvrResponse)
        End Using

        ' close streams
        dstream.Close()
        dstream.Dispose()
        response.Close()

        Try
            ' use json serialier to parse the result(s)
            ' convert SvrRsponse to Dictionary
            SvrResponses = CType(json.DeserializeObject(SvrResponseStr), 
                                    Dictionary(Of String, Object))

            ' get stuff from Dictionary
            imgToken.AccessToken = Convert.ToString(SvrResponses("access_token"))
            imgToken.RefreshToken = Convert.ToString(SvrResponses("refresh_token"))
            imgToken.AcctUserName = Convert.ToString(SvrResponses("account_username"))

            ' convert expires_in to a point in time
            Dim nExp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(SvrResponses("expires_in")))
            imgToken.Expiry = Date.Now.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 0, nExp))

            ' Pins are single use
            ' throw it away since it is no longer valid 
            myPin = ""

        Catch ex As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            myResult = imgUrResults.TokenParseError
        End Try

        Return myResult


    End Function

    ' public interface to check params before trying to upload
    Public Function UploadImage(filename As String, Optional Anon As Boolean = False) As imgUrResults

        If AnonOnly Then
            Return DoImageUpLoad(filename, AnonOnly)
        Else
            If IsTokenValid() = False Then
                Return imgUrResults.InvalidToken
            End If
        End If

        ' should be the job of the calling app to test for FileExist
        Return DoImageUpLoad(filename, Anon)

    End Function

    ' actual file uploader
    Private Function DoImageUpLoad(fileName As String, Optional Anon As Boolean = False) As imgUrResults
        Dim result As imgUrResults = imgUrResults.OK
        LastImageLink = ""

        Try
            ' create a WebClient 
            Using wc = New Net.WebClient()
                ' read image
                Dim values = New NameValueCollection() From
                        {
                            {"image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName))}
                        }
                ' type of headers depends on whether this is an ANON or ACCOUNT upload
                If Anon Then
                    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientID)
                Else
                    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & imgToken.AccessToken)
                End If

                ' upload, get response
                Dim response = wc.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml", values)

                ' read response converting byte array to stream
                Using sr As New StreamReader(New MemoryStream(response))
                    Dim uplStatus As String
                    Dim SvrResponse As String = sr.ReadToEnd

                    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(SvrResponse)
                    ' get the status of the request
                    uplStatus = xdoc.Root.Attribute("status").Value
                    result = GetResultFromStatus(uplStatus)

                    If result = imgUrResults.OK Then
                        LastImageLink = xdoc.Descendants("link").Value

                        ' only overwrite the server result status
                        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastImageLink) Then
                            ' avoid NRE elsewhere
                            LastImageLink = ""
                            ' we did something wrong parsing the result
                            ' but this one is kind of minor
                            result = imgUrResults.OtherAPIError
                        End If
                    End If

                End Using

                If UseClipboard AndAlso (result = imgUrResults.OK) Then
                    Clipboard.SetText(LastImageLink)
                End If

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim errMsg As String = ex.Message

            ' rate limit
            If ex.Message.Contains("429") Then
                result = imgUrResults.RateLimitError

                ' internal error
            ElseIf ex.Message.Contains("500") Then
                result = imgUrResults.ServerError

            End If
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function GetResultFromStatus(status As String) As imgUrResults

        Select Case status.Trim
            Case "200"
                Return imgUrResults.OK
            Case "400"
                Return imgUrResults.BadRequestFormat
            Case "401"
                Return imgUrResults.AuthorizationError
            Case "403"
                Return imgUrResults.Forbidden
            Case "404"
                Return imgUrResults.NotFound
            Case "429"
                Return imgUrResults.RateLimitError
            Case "500"
                Return imgUrResults.ServerError
            Case Else
                ' Stop - work out other returns
                Return imgUrResults.UknownStatus
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Function GetResultFromStatus(status As Int32) As imgUrResults
        ' some places we get a string, others an integer
        Return GetResultFromStatus(status.ToString)
    End Function

End Class
```

## HOW TO USE IT

The process requires a web browser for the user to navigate and request a PIN. For testing/development, I used a WebBrowser control and snagged the PIN from the returned page.

Note: for testing, my imgUR account was setup as DESKTOP, since we are sending from a DESKTOP app. Also, this is for YOU sending images to YOUR account.  There is not a way for OTHERS to upload to YOUR account without giving out your secret ID and/or embedding your master ImgUR Login and password in the App.  That is how ImgUR designed it.

**A.  Create an imgUR object:**

```
Friend imgUR As imgurAPI
imgUR = New imgurAPI(<your Client ID>,<your secret code>)
```

**B.  Get a Pin - Method One**

```
' pass the app's WebBrowser Control
imgUR.RequestPinBrowser(wb)
```

This will take you to a imgur page where you must authorize the issue of a PIN for uploading to your account.  Enter your Account Name, Password, Click ALLOW.  A new page with the PIN will be displayed.  Copy the PIN from the webpage to some other control which can feed it to the imgurAPI Class.

There is code below to parse the PIN page and get it into another control.

**Method Two**

- Using your own external browser, go to

`https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize? client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=pin&state=ziggy`

- Log In
- Copy the PIN you receive into a `TextBox` or something to send it to the imgurAPI:
- Set pin: `imgUR.Pin = <<PIN YOU RECEIVED>>`

The process is the same either way, just a matter of whether you want to have to include a WebBrowser control in your form.  PINs are only good for a short time, so you must use it to get an access token right away.

**C.  Get Access token**

```
' imgUrResults is an enum exposed by the class
Dim result As imgurAPI.imgUrResults = imgUR.RequestToken
```

Notes:

- the imgUR class will retain the token
- tokens currently expire in 1 hour (3600 seconds)

**D:  Upload a File**
Upload using `imgUR.UploadImage(filename, boolAnon)`

Filename - the file to upload

boolAnon - Boolean flag. False = upload this file to your account vs the Anon general pool method.

Example:

```
' get token
Dim result As imgurAPI.imgUrResults = imgUR.RequestToken

' check result
If result = imgurAPI.imgUrResults.OK Then
    ' assumes the file exists
    imgUR.UploadImage("C:\Temp\London.jpg", False)
Else
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error getting access token. Status:{0}",
        result.ToString))
End If
```

After the file uploads, the procedure looks for the link in the response.   If the link can be parsed, it will be available from the `LastImageLink` property and pasted to the ClipBoard as well.

### **Misc Properties, Settings and Methods**

**LastImageLink** (String) - URL of the last image uploaded

**UseClipBoard** (Bool)  -  When true, imgurAPI class posts the link to the uploaded image to the Clipboard

**TokenExpiry** (Date) - The DateTime that the current token expires

**GetTokenTimeRemaining**() As TimeSpan - A TimeSpan representing how long before the current token expires

**Public Function GetTokenCountdown()** As String - Formatted string of TimeRemaining

**Public WriteOnly Property Pin** As String - the PIN required to get an access token

**Public Function IsTokenValid()** As Boolean - is the current token valid

**Public Function IsTokenExpired**() As Boolean - simple Boolean version of TimeRemaining vs DateTime.Now

**Notes**

- Tokens can be renewed or extended.  But since they last for an hour, this seems plenty.
- PINS are only good for a short time.  Once a PIN is exchanged for a token the imgurAPI (this class) clears the PIN.  If there is a problem getting the Token, you will have to get a new PIN first (or paste the last one if you just got it a few minutes ago).
- Uploaded images are not visible to the world at large unless/until you change the setting on your account.
- You can reset your SecretID  (Settings -> Applications).  If you do, you will need to also reset it for apps using this API class, and recompile (or read it from a config file).

If you use a `WebBrowser` control to get a PIN, you can add this code to the `DocumentCompleted` event to scrape the PIN from the HTML:

```
' wb is the control
Dim htmlDoc As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument = wb.Document
Dim elP As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement = htmlDoc.GetElementById("pin")

If elP IsNot Nothing Then
    sPin = elP.GetAttribute("value")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sPin) = False Then
       ' user has to push the button for `imgUR.Pin = tbPIN.Text`
       ' this is in case the HTML changes, the user can override
       ' and input the correct PIN
       Me.tbPIN.Text = sPin
    End If

End If
```

---

### About the OAuth Model

*this is unofficial - info learned from reading the docs and working with the API.  Applies to imgur API v3 as of this date.*

There is **nothing** automated about getting a PIN.  One way or another you must navigate to a URL in a browser and enter your account name and Password to get a PIN.  This is by design so that you, yourself, personally are authorizing some external app to access your account content.

**Method One** above uses a .NET WebBrowser control to do this.  With this method we can be sure that both you and the imgur class are using the same Endpoint/URL because it sends you there via the browser control.

**Method Two** is just you go there in some browser, any browser.  Log in, get a PIN, and paste it to the imgurAPI class.

No matter the method, the correct Endpoint/URL to use is:

https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=pin&state=foobar

Using a browser on the form using the imgurAPI class, we obviously we can be sure that both you and the class are using the same URL and ClientID.  The code for `DocumentComplete` fetches the PIN into the TextBox **only** you still need to set it in the class:

```
myimgUR.PIN = tbPinCode.Text
```

**PINS are single use, and expire.**

So when developing especially, and you stop the code, add some stuff then rerun naturally, the code will no longer have the old Token or PIN. If the last PIN was recent and *not* submitted, you might not have to get a new one, but I find it is hard to remember if that is the case.

The class treats PINS as single use.  Once a Token has been received, it clears out the variable since they have been used and are no longer valid.

---

**Final Edit**

- Added an **Anon Only** mode

To use the class to upload ONLY in Anon mode (to the general site, not your account), the SecretID is not needed.  For this, use the new constructor overload:

```
Public Sub New(clientID As String)
```

This sets the class to work an Anon ONLY and certain methods will return an error or throe an exception when using Account based methods such as `GetToken`.  If you initialize it with just ClientID, it remains in **AnonOnly** mode until you recreate the object with the both the ClientID and SecretID.

There is no real reason to use it as AnonOnly (unless you do not have an account) since the UploadImage method allows you to specify it as an Anon upload by file:

```
Function UploadImage(filename As String, 
                     Optional Anon As Boolean = False) As imgUrResults
```

- Revised/clarified the imgUrResults Enum

This is meant to be all-encompassing: some returns indicate a problem detected by the class, others are server responses which are simply passed along.

- Removed `IsTokenExpired`

`IsTokenValid` is more thorough.  There are other methods to get the time remaining or the actual Expiry.

- Added assorted error trapping/handling

  - Check for a valid WebBrowser control when requesting a PIN
  - Refined the method used to get the server status code after an image is uploaded
  - Reworked some handling to give prioritize remote server status over class returns

.

Comment: Your answer was awesome, but I'm having problems with the "RequestToken" method, it throws an exception, I'm trying to use the method "One" to get the pin because is the one that seems automated and that is what I needed, please could you see my question update? PS: also, in your notes, the documentcompleted method you mean to use it with the method one, or with the method two when getting the pin? maybe that is where I'm failing? anyways I've tried to use it with the method One also but I didn't cant get the pin

Comment: See, my intention was to develop a mini CLI app that the only person that will use it is me, the app should be accessed from the contextmenu of image filetypes then the program starts and I pass the filename as an argument, and the ClientID and ClientSecret are two things that are predefined, as you can note what Im trying to mean is that the program should upload the file "in one step" just running the program via contextmenu cliking an image, I already did the same kind of app using ImagesHack and I didn't find any problem and any required authorization (now ImagesHack became a paid service)

Comment: Then my last question about your answer is this: Knowing all the essential data such as my ClientId and ClientSecret (and my username and password ofc) that will never be different and will not change while I use the program that I've in mind, really using imgur API does not exists a way to automate the task of uploading to my account and I need to manualy "authorize me" in a webbrowser ctrl clicking a button every time that I try to upload an image? If that is the case then I understand that there is nothing to do and this should be solved, but if not then please could clarify how to?

Comment: Or maybe I'm confussing things and maybe I should did a different question like this: The person who obtained the ClientId and ClientSecret to use Imgur API It's also necesary for me to obtain (manualy) a Pin or token? If I'm the only one who will use the program (with your Class implemented)?

Comment: There is no way to get a PIN thru the OAuth API without logging in to authorize access and what I warned about in the June 15 comment before starting on this.  See, imgur **has no way to know** that it is only you authorizing yourself.  A CTM type thing seems dicey too because you would be generating lots of tokens, perhaps concurrently.  That said, there MIGHT be a way to HACK the authorize endpoint and feed your Account Name and Password to the log in page and then SUBMIT it. That is a whole different issue/topic/question.  Maybe change the CTM to copy imgs to a queue for a GUI upload?

Comment: Really what you are explaining me its a totally deception (from imgur service), again I ask sorry for my English 'cause I didn't understood properly that little and very important detail that you've mentioned that day about the pin. on the other hand, I hope you do not feel your help and your shared work is in vain, maybe me (and sure others) could adapt this to automate it in a future, I'll keep your Class also to learn and I'm gonna try to automate the webbrowser, thanks for your time.

Comment: ' What is your change ': really it's any important change, just deleted all related about authorization and added documentation for the rest but improved the GetResultFromStatus method.

Comment: I don't understand why your answer has only 1 upvote and is mine xD, PS: so the 'Authorizationfailed' and 'RateLimitError' status are not needed for anonym upload 'cause those responses can't raise, right?

Comment: I could share the (more) modifications that I've did? I'm confussed about whether really the events that I've added in my code could raise or not when uploading an image ('cause the try/catch of the webbrowser control that maube keeps the events that are inside), if you could help me to clarify that thing here is the (unfinished) source: http://www.mediafire.com/?lqp6cr4m0f0qejt