# Authenticate Google OAuth2 using ASP.NET with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app that will interact with the YouTube API. I have never done OAuth before. While I am definitely comfortable with the concept, I need to learn exactly how to implement it.

I am using VS Express 2013, programming in VB. My app is a Web Forms app (Non MVC), but I have opted to use the Empty Web App template to avoid all the unnecessary baggage that comes with their template.

I'm looking for a guide that will lead me through each of the following:

1. The set-up in the Google Developer Console
2. What I need to do in my site to interact with the Google API (I think I need to have an /Oauth2callback folder?)
3. What code do I need to successfully retrieve the refresh token, as well as trade it in for the scope tokens?

I know it's a lot - so I'm not looking for anyone to type it all here - but if anyone can point me to a good step-by-step, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks - I read through this, but wasn't sure how to put this in action in VB. All of their sample code is C# MVC. I do appreciate the link, though!

Comment: the differences between C# and VB are pretty minimal. [Here is a VB OAuth example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24270278/1070452) in VB, but it is for imgur, not google and it is WinForms not WebForms.  Between the 2 resources maybe you can work out what is needed.