# How to implement 2-legged oAuth for Instagram in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, instagram-api

A year ago I was able to call https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tagname/media/recent?client_id=myclientid&count=500 and I would get the requested results. Now it seems Instagram requires authentication through oAuth.

My problem is I need to gather Instagram posts for a database without user log in. All I have is my app Client_Id. So I suppose I need to use 2-legged authentication. There will be no user logging in. Just an .EXE pulling posts with a certain Tag.

I've been looking for examples using '*oAuth2*', '*DotNetOpenAuth*', '*RestSharp*', '*Instasharp*' and '*Instagram C# Wrapper*', but I have found little to no references.

Has someone implemented anything similar? Or does someone know how to to this?

I have a **Client_Id**, **Client_Secret** and in turn I need an **Access_Token** to call https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=myredirecturi&response_type=token

Though I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: *generally* in OAuth2 you use the Client ID and Secret to get a PIN which you use to get an access token.  Someone has to authorize it though

Comment: That's what I assumed, though I've seen no helpful reference or example

Comment: imgUr uses OAuth too and the process is the same for most of these with small changes to the syntax in keys and submit strings.  Maybe [this answer will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24270278/1070452)