# How to upload image file to imgur?

Tags: c#, image-uploading, imgur

I am trying to upload an image to Imgur. I have taken a client ID and client secret but when I tried to upload data an exception is thrown. The exception says "The remote server returned an error. 400 : bad request". Maybe my client id is wrong because i am not sure that it's correct key to use. I have got it from developers.google.com and it's an OAuth client ID for the type "Other".  How can I fix this problem?

My code:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["image"] = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Image.png"));
        values["key"] = myClientID;
        byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml", values);
        string response = Encoding.Default.GetString(responseBytes);
        client.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(responseBytes)));

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Edit: I have just realized that the main problem is because of the client ID is wrong. So getting a new client ID from https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient fixed the problem. And the code to upload is just like :

```
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath))}
            };
            w.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clid);
            byte[] response = w.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml", values);

            Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(response)));
            //now process response as you'd like. the link is encapsulated by <link></link> in the response.
        }
```

Comment: [Accessing imgUr thru OAuth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24270278/1070452).  It covers anon and user account uploads

Comment: I have reviewed your code. The upload image method is same as my code. I have modified it like your code but it throws an exception again. This time, the exception code is 403. Forbidden. By the way is my client id taken from the right place, isn't it?

Comment: Also do you have a C# implementation of your code at present? Because the VB code is too long to write it again in C#.

Comment: You should be getting the `client_id` and `client_secret` from Imugr: https://imgur.com/signin?redirect=http://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient

Comment: I implemented the link you gave to my code. But it couldn't solve my issue.  It says "403 forbidden" on the upload line. Today I realise that some Imgur  features such as uploading and opening an image are limited or disabled in Turkey by the government. A null image returns if you try to upload using browsers without VPN . Maybe "403 Forbidden" error occurs because of this problem. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, I have just solved the problem. The code was correct, but my client ID had some problem. I have got a new client ID and response is returned correctly. That's all. Thanks for your efforts.