# How to read inbox Outlook.com mails from WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, outlook

### SCENARIO

---

I would like to develop a very simple app written in C# or Vb.Net using **WinForms** tech., that will help me to automate a simple task that consist in access to my **Outlook.com** account to read my emails received from **Youtube** then extract the video urls.

### PROBLEM

---

My networking related knowledges are not good, I'm stuck at the most important point trying to find the easiest way to acchieve that task (I mean official Microsoft APIs for .Net or 3rd party APIs or other way to be able do this), trying to apply the required **OAuth2** autorizathion to access the email account.

I know that the following code is not focused in the right direction because the lack of authorization, but I don't know how to implement that neither how to read the emails, so this is what I tried:

```
string url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages";
string result = "";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";

try {
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        result = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}
```

### QUESTION

---

How I could access to my **Outlook.com** account to read the title and the content of the inbox emails that I have?. And, additionally but optionally to respond (only if possible and is not too much ask), how I could delete a email?.

Note that this question reffers to **Outlook.com** online service, not to **Outlook**'s desktop client neither the usage of their *COM* libraries or **Office365**.

### ANSWER REQUISITES

---

I know that I'm no one to ask for help and put some requisites, all kind of help is appreciated for me, but this time I need to put a special requisite, because my head got crazy trying to understand, use and adapt **OAuth2** solutions that were made from scratch, it generates very long codes that I don't understand at all, it's too much for me.

For that reason, I will accept an answer in this question only if the provided solution is based in the usage of a 3rd pary library that will facilitate all this task because it will serve as a complete abstraction of the **OAuth2** implementation, like **[RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp)**, **[CodeScales](http://www.codescales.com/)** or **[DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/)**, or whichever other (free)lib that will handle the required things for me instead of the need to develop the **OAuth2** algorithms by myself from scratch.

### RESEARCH

---

My investigation started reading **[this](https://dev.outlook.com/)** Microsoft's Outlook dev. page, following to **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations)** Mail API reference, **[this](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi)** REST API documentation, **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx)** Outlook.com API, **[this](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/GetStarted)** kind of getting started article, and ending in **[this](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet)** fully illustrative example using ASP.Net.

What I have taken in clear from the Microsoft articles is just... nothing of nothing, I've registered the app and created the client id and the secret, but Microsoft does not provide any example for **Winforms** so I tried to translate their official **ASP.NET** example to **WinForms** without success.

After that waste of time, I found **[this](http://oauth.net/code/)** **OAuth** documentation page which provides some libraries for .NET that I imagine will facilitate the OAuth2 authorization, then I discovered the **[DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/)** library which seems very complete, and also I found **[this](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-outlook-com-imap-web-applications)** code sample for Outlook using **DotNetOpenAuth** but again it is for **ASP.NET**, and also **[these](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/tree/master/src/OAuth)** generic and official **DotNetOpenAuth**'s code samples but I can't find any thing that could help me for what I want to do.

Comment: There is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24270278/1070452) which utilizes OAuth in Winforms with step by step instructions.  The endpoints would be different and likely the exact request format, but the *process* is the same: OAuth is OAuth.

Comment: @Plutonix Is great to know that I could rehuse the code that you've provided for this purpose, of course I know that my real problem is with the OAuth concept comprehension and the implementation in .NET code, the only demostrative OAUTH2 example for WinForms I have to learn from is yours which is hardcoded for Imgur service, it was very explanatory but I don't understand which would be the required modifications to successfully adapt the code to Outlook.com API request format. If you could guide me a little bit I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Just about everything you need to know is at: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi.  The endpoints are listed right there and are easy to find in the ImgUr code - RequestToken and DoImageUpLoad.  Outlook has different tokens depending on whether you want mail, calendar etc - the API links are on the same page

Comment: I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: From http://dotnetopenauth.net/: `Compiled library that adds support for your site visitors to login...`, `Give your site members their own...` and `...ou can customize how OpenID will operate on your site...`. I havent read beyond that, but it looks like that is for the server side, not a winforms app.

Comment: Maybe you are confused by different types of OAuth flows. Flow that is most used, and is used in all examples, is authorization code flow. It **requires** you to use browser. However, you can use WinForms browser control to do that. There is also client credentials flow, where you just ask user for his password and exchange that for access token directly (no browser required). However this might or might not be suitable in your case. It's not clear from your question how far did you get with that and do you understand the above.

Comment: Do you exclusively want to use RestSharp or DotNetOpenAuth? In fact Microsoft has two packages that works which are: Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (ADAL) and Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0, I can provide a winforms sample with these. Note: they requires your outlook.com account to support the REST apis as explained here in the "REST API availability chapter:" https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted

Comment: @Evk "**There is also client credentials flow, where you just ask user for his password and exchange that for access token directly (no browser required)**" Thanks for clarifying these details, that is what I really would like to do, From WinForms I would like to perform a little task in background WITH NO MANUAL USER INTERACTION (from a WebBrowser, just to authorize credentials if necessary) to access my email account then I'll do a very simple web-scrapping on my emails of Inbox directory to extract some urls inside the email bodies.

Comment: @Simon Mourier "**Do you exclusively want to use RestSharp or DotNetOpenAuth?**" Hi, see please in the **ANSWER REQUISITES** paragraph I explained that I agree to use whichever library, however, related to **OAuth2** I only know the libs that I mentioned then I only mentioned those, If `Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0` (or the other you mentioned) doesn't require to have installed Office product and if with that I can access my account to parse/scrap my Inbox emails at runtime then of course it would be a perfect solution I think, thanks very much.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Maybe do you know how I can determine whether my email account support REST API before letting you wasting time in write a entire solution that maybe will not work in this scenario for that reason?. (I know, one answer is "trying to use the API on you account to compare the message returned with what says the REST API availability chapter", but I'm not really sure to do that)

Comment: The thing is, if your account has not been migrated yet (mine wasn't, I had to create a new one for testing and it works with this new one), I don't think you will be able to use any REST/JSON to outlook.com anyway. I'll post my sample when I find 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to follow the tutorial here: [Get Started with Mail, Calendar, and Contacts REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) but I will try to simplify it and demonstrate it with a Winforms sample.

### Register App

First things first, you need to create and register an application to the  Application Registration Portal (you should only have to do this once for a given application of course):

1. create an app
2. generate a new password
3. add a platform, and choose mobile ("mobile" here means "any device", or "not for a browser"...)
4. don't forget to click on save!

### Authentication

Now, in your "any device" code (including winforms), you'll need to authenticate. The simplest way is to use ADAL ("Active Directory Authentication Library"). The source is available here https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet and the binary is available as a nuget.

Unfortunately, the latest version which you can get on nuget today named **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** does not work for me (It had a bug I've reported here https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/412 that's already been fixed, but now the server complains about some app vs server incompatibility).

So you must use the old "Experimental" one (keep that in mind as someday in the future, we'll have to switch): [Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)

You want to make sure you use the proper scopes when you do acquire an auth token. Scopes are defined here: [Outlook mail, calendar, and contacts scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/authenticate-office-365-apis-using-v2#bk_Outlookscopes) and represent an area of permission. Without specifying scope, you can do nothing else but authenticate.

So, if you want to read mails, use the "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read" scope.

When you try the application, after the authentication dialog, it should display to the user the consent screen (here we see we asked for mail scope: "Read Your Mail"):

[image]

### Office/Outlook/OData API

Once authentication works, you can use the REST api directly which is not that easy, or be lazy and use another package: [Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/) that will do all underlying REST/OData magic for you. The good news is this API is quite complete so it should allow you to do other things like, message creation, delete, etc.

There is an important remark for the outlook.com case: not all accounts are enabled for this whole REST API (check the "REST API availability" chapter here: [Outlook Mail](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet)), so you might want to create a new one for testing.

Here is the winforms code for a sample app that will query 10 messages and add them to a listbox.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
        private const string clientId = "blablabl-abla-blab-abla-blablablab"; // TODO: put your application id here
        private const string redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"; // put your redirect uri here (should be the same)

        // we cache the token for the duration of this form
        // you could/should use the FileCache class provided in the sample here https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet
        private TokenCache _cache = new TokenCache();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // since all packages force async,
            // we have to avoid threading issues
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => GetMessages()));
        }

        private async void GetMessages()
        {
            // use the Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory nuget package for auth
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, _cache);
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                new[] { "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read" },
                null,
                clientId,
                new Uri(redirectUri),
                new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, this));

            // use the Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0 nuget package from now on
            var client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), () => Task.FromResult(result.Token));

            var messages = await client.Me.Messages
                                        .Take(10) // get only 10 messages
                                        .ExecuteAsync();

            // fill some list box
            // (beware, some messages have a null subject)
            foreach (var msg in messages.CurrentPage)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(msg.Subject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you make things veary easy!, however I have problems to use it. I'm not sure why but when I attempt to put my username and password in the Microsoft's authentication window, after I put the username it automatically tries to login instead of waiting for the password input on the textbox below, when the username textbox lost focus it tries to login, no way, I don't understand if its an error on the libraries or what else. To solve it I first need to introduce the password, then use the textbox above to introduce the username. This is also happening to you?

Comment: But, the most mportant problem I have is that it does not recognices my account!!!, the authentication window says that the user id or password is not found, and of course I'd ensured to be using the right username and password of my Outlook.com account. Is this related to the REST api support that you've mentioned, or I'm missing another required requisite?. This is a little bit confussing, one link that you've provided in your explanations is pointing to Office365 login site, and the app's authentication window seems to be for Office365 accounts, not for Outlook.com!. What I need to do?.

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused then I need to ask this: The solution that you kindly have provided, follows what I explained in my question?: `Note that this question reffers to Outlook.com online service, not to Outlook's desktop client neither the usage of their COM libraries or Office365.`, because I don't have an Office365 account and I don't know anyting about it, I need to use this for a Outlook.com mail account.

Comment: Maybe I didn't specified the things in a good way: Is this code working to access on a Hotmail email account? (**https://outlook.live.com/owa/**), if not (and seems not because the auth. window login doesn't recognice my account), what kind of Microsoft's email account I should need to create or what kind of Microsoft's service to register?.

Comment: Yes, this code definitely works for outlook.com and hotmail.com accounts,. I've tested it. But only if the account supports REST API availability as I said. If it doesn't you should get a message stating the account has not been migrated. You can create a new account on outlook.com if you want. The fact the login window updates itself once the mail edit box has lost focus is how the way the whole thing works on Microsoft side. It does not try to login, it just updates depending on the type of account it detects. This is normal, but it may depends on your context (I suggest to clear cookies).

Comment: This is really an awesome smart answer, sincerelly, you saved me weeks or months of investigation and probablly with no luck. One little thing I will ask, the popup with the "Yes/No" question of the image that you shared, really it is fully necessary to display it always in each application run?, is this handled always by Microsoft server side, or I could do something with the libs. to accept the permission window once then "remember" the kind of "token" and forget about it in next app runs?.

Comment: Also (and really this is the last question), did you or are you planning to report what you've said here: "**that's already been fixed, but now the server complains about some app vs server incompatibility**", seems very important consequence to fix, I ask this because I'm scared if the experimental build that now I will use maybe will be incompatible in the future while the most recent build still unfixed then If that happens and if I understood you good, I couldn't anymore still access to my Outlook.com account using your solution?.

Comment: Yes the consent screen is absolutely mandatory, that's the whole principe of these security protocols, it's up to the user to authorize the auth provider (here Microsoft) to give a token to your app. It's 100% handled by the auth provider. About the server incompatibility, I suppose it *can* work with new non-experimental ADAL, but I've not investigated more as the API is a bit different (note: the outlook client is *not* experimental, only auth). I suppose Microsoft will update it's documentation sometimes in the future. You can ask them creating an issue on ADAL's github (like I did).

Comment: Maybe could you help me here?, I think it could be a question easy answerable because your experience: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366991/how-to-wait-for-authenticationcontext-acquiretokenasync-synchronouslly

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to share the (almost)final solution, I extended a little bit the solution provided by @**Simon Mourier**, to iterate all the emails of a specific folder and, if the email is from Youtube, scrap the urls inside, then recytle the email.

When to apply this?, well, just adapt it for any case on which you need to parse the emails, my case is very specific, I have around 500 channel subscriptions so I accumulate around 200 emais from Youtube in a month, most of the emails are from music channels that I just read the email to copy the url to download it with JDownloader, so this is usefull as a savetimer because it will do all the task for me.

```
Private Const Authority As String = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
Private Const ClientId As String = "OUR API ID"

' Put your redirect uri here (should be the same).
Private Const RedirectUri As String = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

' We cache the token for the duration of this Form.
' You could/should use the FileCache class provided in the sample here: 
' https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet
Private cache As New TokenCache()

Private Sub Form1_Shown() Handles MyBase.Shown
    ' Since all packages force async, we have to avoid threading issues.
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() GetMessages())
End Sub

Private Async Sub GetMessages()

    ' Use the 'Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' Nuget package for auth.
    Dim authContext As New AuthenticationContext(Authority, cache)
    Dim result As AuthenticationResult =
        Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync({"https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite"},
                                            Nothing, ClientId, New Uri(RedirectUri),
                                            New PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, Me))

    ' Use the 'Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0' Nuget package from now on.
    Dim client As New OutlookServicesClient(New Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"),
                                            Function() Task.FromResult(result.Token))

    ' I have a rule set to automatically move all emails received from Youtube to a folder with name "Youtube".
    Dim folder As IMailFolder =
       Await client.[Me].MailFolders.Where(Function(f As IMailFolder) f.DisplayName = "Youtube").ExecuteSingleAsync()

    Dim messages As IPagedCollection(Of IMessage) =
        Await client.[Me].MailFolders.GetById(folder.Id).Messages.ExecuteAsync()

    Do While True
        Me.ParseYoutubeMessages(messages.CurrentPage)

        If messages.MorePagesAvailable Then
            messages = Await messages.GetNextPageAsync
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub

Private Async Sub ParseYoutubeMessages(ByVal messageList As IReadOnlyList(Of IMessage))

    Dim urlRegex As New Regex("""http://www.youtube.com/.+watch.+uploademail""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    For Each msg As IMessage In messageList

        If (msg.From.EmailAddress.Name.Equals("YouTube", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then

            Dim body As String = msg.Body.Content
            Dim isMatch As Boolean = urlRegex.IsMatch(body)

            If Not (isMatch) Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("Youtube url regex doesn't match.")

            Else
                Dim urlMatches As MatchCollection = urlRegex.Matches(body)
                Dim urls As String() =
                    (From m As Match In urlMatches.Cast(Of Match)
                     Select Environment.NewLine & m.Value).Distinct().ToArray()

                File.AppendAllText("C:\Youtube Urls.txt", String.Join("", urls))

                msg.IsRead = True
                Await msg.MoveAsync("DeletedItems")

            End If

        End If

    Next msg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating this for 2018 -- Microsoft Graph API now has control over granting access to objects in the 365 world, including email. See this link for the 4-step overview: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user