# How to wait for 'AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()' synchronouslly?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office365, adal

First of all, I'm not sure if this is important, but for the reasons mentioned by @**Simon Mourier** in **[him answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170882/how-to-read-inbox-outlook-com-mails-from-winforms)**, I'm using the EXPERIMENTAL build of ADAL, **[this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)**.

---

In the code below, I would like to retrieve an `AuthenticationResult` synchronouslly, so, I will wait for completition of the authentication by `AcquireTokenAsync` method in a synchronous manner.

This is because a boolean flag should be set after the authorization is done (`isAuthorized = true`), but tgis need to happen in a synchronous way, because if not, then I can call other methods of the class that will throw a null reference because the call to `AcquireTokenAsync` didn't finished so the object is null.

The following code does not work, the method will never return, because the call to `AcquireTokenAsync` method seems that indefinitely freezes the thread.

C# (maybe wrong syntax due to online translation):

```
public void Authorize() {
    // Use the 'Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' Nuget package for auth.
    this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.authUrl, this.cache);
    this.authResult = this.authContext.AcquireTokenAsync({ "https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite" }, 
                                                         null, this.clientIdB, this.redirectUriB, 
                                                         new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, this.windowHandleB)).Result;

    // Use the 'Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0' Nuget package from now on.
    this.client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), () => Task.FromResult(this.authResult.Token));
    this.isAuthorizedB = true;
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Public Sub Authorize()

    ' Use the 'Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' Nuget package for auth.
    Me.authContext = New AuthenticationContext(Me.authUrl, Me.cache)

    Me.authResult =
        Me.authContext.AcquireTokenAsync({"https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite"}, 
                                         Nothing, Me.clientIdB, Me.redirectUriB,
                                         New PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, Me.windowHandleB)).Result

    ' Use the 'Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0' Nuget package from now on.
    Me.client = New OutlookServicesClient(New Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"),
                                           Function() Task.FromResult(Me.authResult.Token))

    Me.isAuthorizedB = True

End Sub
```

I researched a little bit and I tried other two alternatives, but happens the same..

1st:

```
ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<AuthenticationResult> t = this.authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scopeUrls.ToArray(), null, this.clientIdB, this.redirectUriB, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, this.windowHandleB)).ConfigureAwait(false);

this.authResult = t.GetAwaiter.GetResult();
```

2nd:

```
this.authResult == RunSync(() => { return this.authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scopeUrls.ToArray(), null, this.clientIdB, this.redirectUriB, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, this.windowHandleB)); })

private AuthenticationResult RunSync<AuthenticationResult>(Func<Task<AuthenticationResult>> func)
{
    return Task.Run(func).Result;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're swimming against the tide here - the mechanisms are provided to you (using `await` or `ContinueWith`) to schedule activity to happen *after* the call to `AcquireTokenAsync` has returned, but you're not using them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to wait for 'AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()' synchronouslly?

I suspect this issue is caused by calling the async method in the UI thread. Currently, my workaround is wrapping the call a new work thread.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Authorize().Wait();
    }

    private Task Authorize()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");

            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync
            (new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite" },
             null,
             "{client_id}",
             new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
             new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, null));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. What you suggested is the first obvious thing that I would have tried, but unfortunately is not possible because doesn't exists such synchronous equivalent method with name `AcquireToken`, at least in the experimental build (which I'm forced to use). The `windowHandleB` is just a `IntPtr` reference pointing to the window handle of the calling Form (so when a valid handle is passed in the args., the Outlook's auth. window is displayed centered over that window).

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I will try to reproduce this issue at my side, BTW, have you tried to remove the this.windowHandleB parameter, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)?

Comment: I can't do that, the `PlatformParameters`'s constructor takes two parameters, there is any overload defined (probably because the experimental build I'm using?). Thanks again for being interested on the problem I have. Anyways, I think the problem is more involved in multi-threading issues.

Comment: I tried the most recent build https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/releases, just to analyze how it works, however, there is any "AcquireToken" sync method defiined too...

Comment: I can reproduce this issue, after looking the source code, it is caused by a HttpClient.PostAsync method does not return.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I suspect this issue is caused by calling the async method in the UI thread. Currently, my workaround is wrapping the call a new work thread. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

I fought this problem for 2 days on Xamarin.Android. It just never returns from the AquireTokenAsync method. The answer is almost comical. You need to add the following in your MainActivity.cs:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Funny thing is, it actually says ContinuationHelper... smh.

Comment: we have documentation on this in our [wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/leveraging-brokers-on-Android-and-iOS#update-mainactivitycs-to-call-back-adalnet)

Comment: @Kaspar any chance of a sample of your code of how you are calling AcquireTokenAsync. I added the OnActivityResult override in the MainActivity, but AcquireTokenAync still does not return. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Same, my code is hitting OnActivityResult but the AcquireTokenAsync never returns ???

Answer (score 4):

> How to wait for 'AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()' synchronouslly?

AcquireTokenAsync() returns a "Task". You just have to wait for it using  ".Wait()". In your main program you just have to do this:

```
Task<AuthenticationResult> res = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
res.Wait();
Console.WriteLine(res.Result.AccessToken);
```