# Microsoft (REST/GRAPH) Authorization Using ASP.NET WebForms VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Nearing a month working on this with little success, any help would be appreciated a lot.

I have to get calendar items from outlook accounts. Managed to get it to work in ASP.NET MVC with C#, ported the code over to VB.NET on ASP.NET WebForms, but with no success.

I can only find code samples and authorization methods that work with MVC, but the application I have to implement it in still uses WebForms (aspx pages)

I've tried both the Microsoft Restful API and the Graph API, but they both only seem to support MVC. Same thing with the authorization methods they require, (Azure AD v1, v2, oauth, sdk)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph Client library may not support the webForm(VB.net), but the Restful Graph API should works well. The restful Graph API can be used by almost any language or framework . For VB.NET on ASP.NET WebForms, because it is not recommended/supported by the official now, so many logic we need to handle **by ourselves（HttpClient） or use 3rd lib**.

**Just one vb.net sample for your reference**, ignore the WebForms itself, just copy the code to where you need and modify the logic to what you want.

> ```
> https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/microsoft_graph_oauth2_access_token.asp
> ```

```
Dim oauth2 As New Chilkat.OAuth2
Dim success As Boolean

'  This should be the port in the localhost callback URL for your app.
'  The callback URL would look like "http://localhost:3017/" if the port number is 3017.
oauth2.ListenPort = 3017

oauth2.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
oauth2.TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"

'  Replace these with actual values.
oauth2.ClientId = "MICROSOFT-GRAPH-CLIENT-ID"
'  This is your app password:
oauth2.ClientSecret = "MICROSOFT-GRAPH-CLIENT-SECRET"

oauth2.CodeChallenge = False
'  Provide a SPACE separated list of scopes.
'  See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

'  Important: To get a refresh token in the final response, you have to ask for "offline_access" scope
oauth2.Scope = "openid profile offline_access user.readwrite mail.readwrite mail.send"

'  Begin the OAuth2 three-legged flow.  This returns a URL that should be loaded in a browser.
Dim url As String = oauth2.StartAuth()
If (oauth2.LastMethodSuccess <> True) Then
    Debug.WriteLine(oauth2.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


'  At this point, your application should load the URL in a browser.
'  For example,
'  in C#:  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
'  in Java: Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
'  in VBScript: Set wsh=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'               wsh.Run url
'  in Xojo: ShowURL(url)  (see http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/ShowURL)
'  The Microsoft account owner would interactively accept or deny the authorization request.

'  Add the code to load the url in a web browser here...
'  Add the code to load the url in a web browser here...
'  Add the code to load the url in a web browser here...



'  Now wait for the authorization.
'  We'll wait for a max of 30 seconds.
Dim numMsWaited As Integer = 0
While (numMsWaited < 30000) And (oauth2.AuthFlowState < 3)
    oauth2.SleepMs(100)
    numMsWaited = numMsWaited + 100
End While

'  If there was no response from the browser within 30 seconds, then
'  the AuthFlowState will be equal to 1 or 2.
'  1: Waiting for Redirect. The OAuth2 background thread is waiting to receive the redirect HTTP request from the browser.
'  2: Waiting for Final Response. The OAuth2 background thread is waiting for the final access token response.
'  In that case, cancel the background task started in the call to StartAuth.
If (oauth2.AuthFlowState < 3) Then
    oauth2.Cancel()
    Debug.WriteLine("No response from the browser!")
    Exit Sub
End If



'  Check the AuthFlowState to see if authorization was granted, denied, or if some error occurred
'  The possible AuthFlowState values are:
'  3: Completed with Success. The OAuth2 flow has completed, the background thread exited, and the successful JSON response is available in AccessTokenResponse property.
'  4: Completed with Access Denied. The OAuth2 flow has completed, the background thread exited, and the error JSON is available in AccessTokenResponse property.
'  5: Failed Prior to Completion. The OAuth2 flow failed to complete, the background thread exited, and the error information is available in the FailureInfo property.
If (oauth2.AuthFlowState = 5) Then
    Debug.WriteLine("OAuth2 failed to complete.")
    Debug.WriteLine(oauth2.FailureInfo)
    Exit Sub
End If


If (oauth2.AuthFlowState = 4) Then
    Debug.WriteLine("OAuth2 authorization was denied.")
    Debug.WriteLine(oauth2.AccessTokenResponse)
    Exit Sub
End If


If (oauth2.AuthFlowState <> 3) Then
    Debug.WriteLine("Unexpected AuthFlowState:" & oauth2.AuthFlowState)
    Exit Sub
End If


Debug.WriteLine("OAuth2 authorization granted!")
Debug.WriteLine("Access Token = " & oauth2.AccessToken)

'  Get the full JSON response:
Dim json As New Chilkat.JsonObject
json.Load(oauth2.AccessTokenResponse)
json.EmitCompact = False

'  The JSON response looks like this:

'  {
'   "token_type": "Bearer",
'    "scope": "User.Read Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send",
'    "expires_in": 3600,
'    "ext_expires_in": 0,
'    "access_token": "EwBAA8l6B...",
'    "refresh_token": "MCRMdbe...",
'    "id_token": "eyJ0eXA..."
'  }

'  If an "expires_on" member does not exist, then add the JSON member by
'  getting the current system date/time and adding the "expires_in" seconds.
'  This way we'll know when the token expires.
If (json.HasMember("expires_on") <> True) Then
    Dim dtExpire As New Chilkat.CkDateTime
    dtExpire.SetFromCurrentSystemTime()
    dtExpire.AddSeconds(json.IntOf("expires_in"))
    json.AppendString("expires_on",dtExpire.GetAsUnixTimeStr(False))
End If


Debug.WriteLine(json.Emit())

'  Save the JSON to a file for future requests.
Dim fac As New Chilkat.FileAccess
fac.WriteEntireTextFile("qa_data/tokens/microsoftGraph.json",json.Emit(),"utf-8",False)
```

Another reference for handle the logic by our self but not 3rd lib.

> [Accessing imgUr thru OAuth (uploading to user account)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156678/accessing-imgur-thru-oauth-uploading-to-user-account/24270278#24270278)